# Why do I have to restart Intellij for it to recognize Lombok annotations?

Tags: intellij-idea, lombok, intellij-lombok-plugin

I am using intellij & Lombok & I have **annotation processor set to enabled**.

```
IntelliJ IDEA 2020.2 (Community Edition)
Build #IC-202.6397.94, built on July 27, 2020
Runtime version: 11.0.7+10-b944.20 amd64
VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o.
Linux XXXX
GC: ParNew, ConcurrentMarkSweep
Memory: XXXXM
Cores: XX
Non-Bundled Plugins: color.scheme.Gruvbox, Lombook Plugin, org.intellij.scala
Current Desktop: KDE
```

And using Lobmok: `0.30-EAP`

When I create a class like so:

```
@Builder
@Getter
public class Stub {
    private final int f1;
    private final long f2;
}
```

Or if I add a field to an existing class Intellij Complains that: `Variable 'f1' might not have been initialized`.

If I restart Intellij the error goes away.

- Build/Recompiling the class doesn't help
- Maven reload proejct doesn't help
- Build/Build the project doesn't help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IntelliJ IDEA 2020.2 has [a known issue](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-248146) affecting Lombok plug-in. It's fixed in 2020.2.1 release. Please [update](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/download/index.html).